# Summing up digits !

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Hi I have been trying out this [problem](http://mathalon.in/?page=show_problem.php&pid=133):

> Suppose  P(n) is sum of digits of 2^n
>   For example:
>   As 2^15 = 32768 and the sum of its digits is 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26,so P(15)=26.
>   Catulate sum of the P(n) for n=1 to 10000.

Here is my [python code](http://ideone.com/7fAWQ) which is giving **67783431** as answer but the judge doesn't seems to be agree on this:

```
def P(n):
    n = int(1<<n)
    S = 0
    while n != 0:
        S += (n%10)
        n /= 10
    return S

Sum = 0
for i in range(1,10001):
    Sum += P(i)
else:
    print(Sum)
```

Could anybody tell me what's wrong in my approach? I would be appreciate if somebody points me to a mathematical solution for the same.

Comment: @Tretwick Marian: Why don't you bring the code here and also describe the problem. When both the links goes away. This post will become non-relevant.

Comment: Added problem description and code.

Comment: Have you tried printing P(15)? How about P(1000) or P(10000)?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: [Here](http://ideone.com/pNCA1)

Comment: your solution is horribly slow, may be that the problem. memoize, instead of calculating 1<<n every time.

Comment: The algorithm seems to be giving the cumulative sum, is that what you want or do you want the individual sums? It seems to be doing cumulative sums correctly...

Comment: Are Python integers unbounded? Say 1<<64 should have 65 bits at least.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: For 1000 it is giving 1366 which is the correct answer for [PE 16](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=16)

Comment: Python has large-integer support, 1<<10000 is easily handled.

Comment: `n //= 10` will ensure that you're doing floor division. Not sure that's the problem though.

Comment: @alpha-mouse: That's not the problem I got same answer using `pow(2,n)`.

Comment: I verified the same sum, I see nothing wrong with the code, except that Python 3.1 seems to be optimized differently, it fails with some floating point boundary problem. I rewrote the code to use strings instead, and I got the same sum.

Comment: what is the 'else' statement for?

Comment: The `else` part, if present, is executed when the sequence of values is exhausted, as [per the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

Comment: In the comments to the problem, they admit to a mistake; n should start at zero, not 1.  I believe your solution is otherwise correct.

Comment: I believe that the judge is wrong, in which case you'd need to move on or guess the mistake.  Have you tried variations on the problem, such as summing the numbers from 1 to 9999 or 1 to 1000?

Comment: @Tretwick Marian: In can confirm that the solution is 67783431 (with an independent algorithm) if the problem is as you stated. Could you please provide the exact wording of the question? Thanks

Comment: @Tretwick Marian: Ignore my last comment, the issue seem to be solved now and the (modified) right answer is 67783432 (after all ;-).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you had shown the comments, you would've noticed that the site owners, or problem maintainer, is a moron.

He meant to say from "0 to 10000", not "1 to 10000", but apparently the problem cannot be edited, or the maintainer don't want to do it.

The sum is off by 1 since `1<<0` is 1, which adds 1 to the sum.

Try submitting 67783432.

**Note**: I realize that calling the site owners or the maintainer a moron might sound harsh, but when posting content on a site about "Mathematics", accuracy is kinda important. Having such a site without the ability, or the requirement, to fix wrong problems, seems kinda stupid to me.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: Thank you.

Comment: Easiest solution on SO! Just add 1!

Comment: Yes, that was really it. I registered, logged in, read the comments, posted the sum + 1, answer accepted.

Comment: This "1" is what I like to call **Karlsen's Variable Constant**, it's what you have to add to the answer you get, to get the answer that is correct.

Comment: This is the first time I have heard of that site!

Answer (score 3):

A more elegant solution in terms of functional programming might be:

```
>>> P = lambda n: sum(map(int, str(1 << n)))
>>> sum(P(i) for i in xrange(10001))
67783432
```

(Notice this computes the sum of P(i) for i=0 to 10000.)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution takes quite some time to run (more than a minute, anyway). Is there a time limit imposed by the judge on the length of time solutions can take to run?

Also, if you're using Python 3, then the division operator (`/=`) always produces a floating point result. In Python 2, the result would be truncated to an integer with integer inputs.

Actually, with Python 3 I get an overflow error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in P
OverflowError: int/int too large for a float
```

Comment: Didn't want to use a comment for this like the rest of us ;) ?

Comment: I am using Pyth 2.6 and there is no limit for time since only answer needs to be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative implementation that confirms your answer is correct:

```
>>> sum(reduce(lambda x, y: x + int(y), str(2**n), 0) for n in xrange(1, 10001))
67783431
```

Or one that memoizes:

```
>> reduce(lambda x, y: (sum(int(c) for c in str(x[1]*2)) + x[0], x[1]*2), xrange(0, 10000), (0,1))[0]
67783431
```

Comment: Or avoiding reduce: sum(sum(int(c) for c in str(2**n)) for n in range(1, 10001))

Comment: @Tretwick, I used a similar method and got the same answer. Either we are missing something or the judge has the wrong answer.

Comment: I am very new in pyth and I don't I understand that piece of code :/

Comment: I am not very new in python, and I don't understand it either.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since Java cannot produce such large numbers (unless you use BigInteger class - which I have never used ), its better if you use flexible languages like Python

Python gave me 2**1000. its a very huge number whose solution is  **1366**

try this in python

a = 2**1000
print( a )

then take the output from python as a string and take sum each digit